# Handling programmatically added div in jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

i am having problem with handling dynamically added div using jquery ui tabs. My goal is to have just one div element where content of that element is filled depending on what tab user selected. Now i know that when handling tabs, this library needs to be able to access div with id that a href in list points to. So, to add div i used select method,like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var choice = ui.tab.href;
        choice = choice.split("/");
        showContent(choice[choice.length - 1]); //choice -> geting a href value of selected   tab (for example: #tab-1)  
    }
});
```

And in the showContent(choice) something like this:

```
function showContent(choice) {
    div_id = choice.replace("#", "");
    //set content div like
    $("#content").html("<div id='" + div_id + "'>" + some_content + "</div>");
}
```

After this i get right content in div named content (id of div inside is also fine -> in my example DOM contain):

```
<div id="content"><div id="tab-1">content</div></div>
```

But it seems like javascript code dont see newly created div,and tabs dont works with error: "jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier".

Haw can i make javascript see this new div element?

Answer (score 2):

i think you forgot to add this:

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1"> Tab 1</a></li>
```

And after refresh you tab container

```
$( ".#tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```

Comment: this was not my whole code. Anyway, i had a href element for list. And refresh would not help, problem is that tabs just dont work the way i needed it to used this method. See jsfiddle in comment to original post. Btw this is really old thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an [AJAX implementation](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) of JQuery-UI tabs.

This allows you to not store all of the tab content on the page you are storing the content  on.

*Example from JQueryUI Site:*
**JavaScript:**

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
            ui.panel.html(
                "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
   <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
            <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That was on of my ideas, to refresh tabs that way but it doesnt help me. Still getting same error. As i said content is fine buy tabs are not changing.

Comment: What version of Jquery and Jquery-ui are you using?

Comment: version seems not to be important,as even in this fiddle doesnt work (jquery ui 1.9.1 - jquery 1.8.2) and in my project (jquery ui 1.8.16 and jquery 1.6.2)

Comment: and now i see you maybe didnt get my idea. I am not making new tabs, i just want to have only one div element in which i show content depend on selected tab. I need to make inside div with same id as a href value of selected tabs to make this work. Right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was just realizing that myself.  I will continue to take a look at it.

Comment: Maybe one solution is to set selected tab inside select method (based on selected index) and then prevent default action. But i was not being able to do that either. I tried with : $("tabs-1").tabs('select',ui.index) or $tab1.tabs('select',ui.index) and nothing changed.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic Have you looked at the AJAX implementation of JQUERY-UI tabs.  *See Updated Answer*

Comment: Ajax implementation looks nice, but i have specific situation where content i load is actually picture. And as i have a lot of tabs and subtabs number of picture loaded is more then 40 and that bring memory issue in browser.Which is why i tried just changing one div. I can try using ajax here,but i am not shure if browser will load picture if i add them to a href attr of tab list?

Comment: If you have a ajax page that loads the picture it should work just fine.  Also the picture will not load till they click the tab so you wouldn't have to worry about the 40 pictures loading in the background as soon as they hit the page.

Comment: turns out ajax loading of tabs also created automatically div for every selected tab. So here i also end up with bunch of divs and pictures in them. With no big difference from situation where i create them directly in HTML. Maybe setting tabs with just changing one div element is not possible. I know it is not in the "spirit" of tab based page.